# How to reduce union types in typescript without using string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following local state variable

```js
 const [select, setSelect] = useState<'' | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h'>('');
```

and I want to reduce this awkward looking union type, I still want to be specific but I don't want go with string my redux default state looks like following any idea how to improve both of these cases ? Please note my redux state extends further more.

```js
export interface group {
  id: string;
  set: 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h' | 'i'| 'j'| 'k';
  groupStatus: boolean;
}
```

Comment: can enum be used for this ? just a suggestion

Comment: if i understand what you want correctly: you can extract it into a type like so 

`type Letters = "a" | "b" .....`

and then use Letters wherever you need.

Comment: @Dean I mean I have components all over the place and I don't want to abuse casting, the code will look like trash plus it won't serve much of a purpose ..

Comment: you can define the type once then as i described in the above comment, export that type and use it wherever you need. if you mean you want to narrow the type down, then you might need typeguards to infer the type in flow.

Comment: @Dean so simply export from state and use (as type) after the unkonwn component (cast)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a type alias here:

```js
type AllowedValues = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h' | 'i'| 'j'| 'k'

export type group = {
  id: string;
  set: AllowedValues;
  groupStatus: boolean;
}

 const [select, setSelect] = useState<'' | AllowedValues>('');
```

Comment: is normal to export types all over app from state module ? depending on need case or is it a bad practice ?

Comment: `AllowedValues` seems specific to your application. I would place it close to your main api of your app.